# Images next to each other

Tags: graphics

I am using `\hspace{-0.1mm}` to ensure the `image1` and `image2` are right next to each other.  Otherwise, when the pdf viewer is zoomed in, a blank vertical line is seen between the images.  I wonder if there is a more logical way to ensure images are laid out right next to each other.

```
\includegraphics[scale=1]{image1.png}\hspace{-0.1mm}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{image2.png}
```

Comment: Just use a `%` after the first image, without it a space is inserted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\includegraphics[scale=1]{image1.png}%
\includegraphics[scale=1]{image2.png}
```

The percent character comments the end of line that causes a space to be set in horizontal mode.